# Contentful with Nuxt.JS "Expected parameter accessToken"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, contentful

I made a page which pulls data from Contentful. The data is pulling correctly, but buttons which use functions from methods don't work. Live updating of variables (for example, using `v-model`) doesn't work either.

I see this error in the console:

[image: screenshot]

I think this error is the problem. Does anyone know what's wrong? I have no clue how to solve it :(

My contentful.js:

```
const contentful = require('contentful')

const client = contentful.createClient({
  space: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ENV_SPACE_ID,
  accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ENV_ACCESS_TOKEN
})

module.exports = client
```

Code which pulls data:

```
export default {
  layout: "landing_page",
  asyncData() {
    return client
      .getEntries({
        content_type: "landingPage"
      })
      .then(entries => {
        return { contentfulData: entries.items[0].fields };
      });
  },
  computed: {
    styles() {
      return landingPageCss;
    }
  },
  components: {
    priceBox,
    contact,
    home,
    aboutUs,
    footerDiv
  }
};
```

Comment: have you tried outputting the contents of `process.env.CONTENTFUL_ENV_ACCESS_TOKEN`? Maybe the environment isn't being loaded correctly?

Comment: @milgner Yes, it doesn't work :(

Comment: So the question is: how are you setting the environment? Are you using `https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv`? Via another mechanism?

Comment: Yes, I use dotenv

Comment: Okay but then your question isn't about Nuxt or the Contentful API but about your environment not being loaded correctly? You should add some code about how you're loading dotenv and maybe a redacted version of your `.env` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best approach is used dotenv package to that. Set your env keys in `.env` file.

nuxt.config.js file should contain:

```
const env = require('dotenv').config()

export default {
  mode: 'universal',
  ...
  env: env.parsed,
  ...
}
```

Look at this video: https://codecourse.com/watch/using-env-files-with-nuxt

Answer (score 2):

If you use dotenv you need to do following steps:

```
npm install --save-dev @nuxtjs/dotenv
```

Then you install it as an module. Note here if you using Nuxt.js older then v2.9 then you ahve to go to `nuxt.config.js` and put your code into the `module` section:

```
...
   module: [
   '@nuxtjs/dotenv'
 ]
...
```

If there is no `module` section then create one.

If you using newer then v2.9 then you put it into the `buildModules`

```
  ...
   buildModules: [
   '@nuxtjs/dotenv'
 ]
...
```

Your variables that are saved in the `.env` file are now accessable through `context.env` or `process.env`